# Prove the following rule for Fermat 2-power nim multiplication

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I read this question earlier: [Algorithm to multiply nimbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909304/algorithm-to-multiply-nimbers?noredirect=1&lq=1). In this question, a rule about Fermat 2-powers is taken for granted. We define $F_n:=2^{2^n}$ as the $n$th Fermat 2-power. We also use $\otimes$ to represent nim-multiplication, and $\oplus$ to represent nim-addition (nim-addition is equal to bitwise exclusive or). We then define nim-multiplication recursively as follows:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:rule}
x\otimes y=\text{mex}\{(x\otimes b)\oplus(a\otimes y)\oplus(a\otimes b):0\leq a<x,0\leq b<y\},\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Let $x\leq F_n$. The rule then says
$$
F_n\otimes x=
\begin{cases}
F_n\cdot x&\text{ if $x\neq F_n$}\\
\frac32 F_n&\text{ if $x=F_n$}.
\end{cases}
$$

My question is, how can we prove this rule? I don't really see how Fermat 2-powers are at all relevant to the definition given in display (\ref{eq:rule}), and I cannot find a proof of this on Google, which makes me suspicious that a proof is very complicated.

Comment: There is a three page proof of this rule in _Combinatorial Game Theory_ by Aaron Siegel (Chapter IV, Lemma 5.6).